# Why recordsets and recordset returning same data?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am working with node+express and `mssql` npm package. I wonder why the `sql.request` returns the same information in recordsets and recordset. I came to know that the recordset property should return the first record only, but it is failing...

Database:

[image]

Code:

```
var sqlRequest = new sql.Request();

sqlRequest.query("select * from Users", function (err: any, result: any) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  return OkReply("Records fetched", result);
});
```

Result:

```
{
"code": 200,
"message": "Records fetched",
"data": {
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "ID": 0,
                "UserName": "admin",
                "Password": "admin"
            },
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "UserName": "admin2",
                "Password": "admin2"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "UserName": "admin",
            "Password": "admin"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "UserName": "admin2",
            "Password": "admin2"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        2
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why is it failing, change your select to: select * from users; select * from users; and see the difference

Comment: They aren't exactly the same data. `recordset` is only the first result table returned from your SQL query, whereas`recordsets` is an array of all the result tables that were returned. Try something like `select * from users; select * from users;` to make the difference more obvious.

Comment: It is record"SET". As others explained you are getting the first table's result as record SET (IOW recordsets[0]).